# R - Issues with group order/ ggplot dodge barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, bar-chart

I looked through other questions but I didn't find this exact problem

```
company<-c("c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c3","c4","c4", "c4")
subsegment<- c("Sub2","Sub3", "Sub1","Sub2", "Sub3", "Sub1","Sub2", "Sub3", "Sub1","Sub2", "Sub3")
values<-c(120,300,30,300,1800,10,96,277, 10, 400, 1100)
df<- data.frame(company,subsegment, values)
```

That's my code for the data frame and I try to make a grouped barchart:

```
plot.1<- ggplot(df, aes(fill=company, y=values, x=subsegment)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", alpha=0.5)
```

The plot I get is exactly what I want, values for each company grouped by SubSegment... except the subsegments are ordered from left to right in default in alphabetical order "Sub1","Sub2","Sub3" and same for the companies...

I would like the same graphic to appear, but showing first "Sub3" then "Sub1" and last "Sub2"
I would also like for the bars inside each group (inside each subsegment) to be ordered by value from bigger to smaller, instead of just alphabetically.

I attach picture of the graph I get:
[image: plot I get]

Hope the question is clear enough, I want to get the same graph but change order of things in the x axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reorder the `subsegment`, assign `factor` to it and specify the orders in `levels`.

To reorder the bars within dodged bar chart, use `reorder` to order the dodged bars with descending size of `values`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(factor(subsegment, levels = c("Sub3", "Sub1", "Sub2")), 
               values, 
               fill = reorder(company, desc(values)))) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  labs(x = "subsegment", fill = "company")
```

[image: reorder_dodged_bar]

Answer (score 1):

I did it by manipulating the underlying data.  I like to do all my factor munging outside of the ggplot call; I think this makes things cleaner.  Oh the joys of factors:

```
df<- data.frame(company,subsegment, values) %>%
  # subsegment order
  mutate(reorder_subsegment = case_when(
    subsegment == "Sub3" ~ 1,
    subsegment == "Sub1" ~ 2,
    subsegment == "Sub2" ~ 3
  )) %>% 
  mutate(subsegment = reorder(subsegment, reorder_subsegment)) %>% 
  # company order
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(company_by_value = sum(values)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(company = reorder(company, -company_by_value))


ggplot(df, aes(fill=company, y=values, x=subsegment)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge", alpha=0.5)
```